# How to get feedback about a closed question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed, migrated-questions

This question, *[Where is a CAcert's password used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74790323/where-is-a-cacerts-password-used)*, got closed for being unfocused.

Honestly, I thought it was fine. I am still looking for an answer. That said, supposing it was unfocused, or unclear, it is closed now, so I can't even edit it. Even if I did edit it how would anyone see it?

One person's answered with some very generic keystore stuff that didn't relate to my question, directly.

One of the comments kind of answered the question, but I would like more details about how and when the certificate file password is used. His comment implies the the certificate file password is not used by Java or other applications.

I think a possible answer is that Java doesn't actually use the keystore password. However, I don't think the question has to be closed.

Comment: By the way, someone told me part of the problem is that the question was moved from another stack exchange site.  That is why editing is locked.

Comment: Just to be sure, the "edit" link below the tags list is missing/disabled? So you have only actions like "share" and "flag"? Which actions are listed below the tags list?

Comment: If the post ends with a bullet-point list of questions, that's already a red flag for "needs more focus".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Someone edited in the bullet points.  All of them relate to how and when the cacert password is used.

Comment: Does java use the password, do other applications use the password.  Do applications not use the password.  It's all about what this password is used for.

Comment: Its not like I was asking three totally different questions.

Comment: @Progman It says post is locked when you click edit.

Comment: The banner says it's been _returned_ to the Information Security stack - you need to edit it there.

Comment: @snakecharmerb It is closed there because it is off-topic for them.  That's why they moved it to Stack Overflow.  I don't think I can edit there, reopen it, and retransfer it SO.

Comment: I'll take out the bullet points, if someone opens the question.  They weren't even from me.  That was an edit someone put in the question.  I wish I had never accepted the edit.

Comment: I didn't know there was a rule against bullet points.  I didn't even put them in.

Comment: the bullet points isn't the problem, it's the list of unrelated questions part. Answers on stack sites are meant to be a single answer, not a list of answers or a tutorial/guide. Questions should be asked accordingly

Comment: @Kevin B They aren't unrelated.  They all focus on how the password is used.  Basically, what if anything uses that password.

Comment: @GC_ Sorry, i didn't mean to give the impression that your case was unrelated. Just in general.

Comment: @KevinB Also, I did edit question on other site.  Removing the bullet points and condensing the questions.

Comment: You could answer most if not all of your questions by doing a few simple experiments. Go ahead and play with the file and see what happens. Make a backup of course and restore it when you've finished with your experiments. If I'm wrong about this then perhaps your question *could* be more focused and clear.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: You're off by a country mile on this.  Cacerts isn't something you just "play" with.

Comment: @Makoto: I'm quite familiar with it, and of course you can "just play with it". In fact, doing so is really the only way to answer his questions, unless more information about this environment is supplied

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I am experimenting.  I thought someone might actually know the answer.  The issue with experimenting is you might not cover all scenarios.  Also, to your second point, how java uses the truststore is probably fairly standard.  If you needed more information you could have just asked.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk By the way, I am basically assuming java ignores the password.  However, it would have been nice to have someone confirm that before I made the change,

Comment: "Its not like I was asking three totally different questions." Just 3 not totally different questions. 3 QUESTIONS. PS "I realize I don't really understand how java is accessing cacert?" is not a question, it is a statement with a question mark at the end. What is the question that that is not asking?

Comment: I think the actual question boils down to "do you need the password for reading from a keystore/truststore or do you only need it for modifying it" - no?

Comment: I expressed the the question as three quandaries.  They were more like multiple-choice options, then the separate questions.  The spirit of the question was pretty focused. It was all about how the password is used.  A couple different people made the entire question into one sentence.

Answer (score 9):

Honestly I don't see any problems with this question.  Dealing with cacerts in a Java installation, while uncommon, would be something that a programmer would be exposed to dealing with.

On occasion when dealing with certain applications, you need Java to use a different certificate than the ones it comes pre-bundled with.  This could also happen if your institution is using a cert that is valid and signed but isn't in the default trust.  This can break SSH and SSL in silent and frustrating ways.

With the above, I'd argue that the question *is* on-topic here.

If we wanted to get *super* nit-picky about it, the actual question could be rewritten as such:

> I realize I don't really understand how Java is accessing cacert. Does it - or anything - need the cacert password, or do you only need the cacert password when adding or removing certs?

Comment: I would be fine with that edit.

Comment: Can you just edit it in and reopen the question?

Comment: Someone's gonna have to re-migrate it to Stack Overflow again, and that process may be *really* slow.  I did flag the original question when I had first saw this question asked on MSE to see if A Moderator™ could help out with this, since the question totally is valid on this site.  But you could also flag it for moderator attention on Security Stack Exchange and see if they'll migrate it as well, with a link to this Meta question for context.  No guarantees that any of that would happen, though.

Comment: I did appeal it on the other site.  And left a link to this question as you suggested.

Comment: As it is open on SO, I'm just going to delete it on Sec.SE